# Django: Creating a model for a third party class

Tags: python, django, multiple-inheritance

What is a good way for adding a Django model for an existing third party (non-Django) Python class? I tried multiple inheritance like so:

```
class ThirdPartyClass(object):
    pass

class ModelForThirdPartyClass(models.Model, ThirdPartyClass):
    uid = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

but this fails (Django 1.8.7):

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 361, in _prepare
    cls.__doc__ = "%s(%s)" % (cls.__name__, ", ".join(f.name for f in opts.fields))
TypeError: sequence item 4: expected str instance, int found
```

Comment: What are you expecting this to do?

Comment: Well, I want ModelForThirdPartyClass to have all of the attributes and methods of ThirdPartyClass, while also having the Django ORM methods.

Comment: I suspect this is a good case for preferring composition over inheritance.

Comment: @DanielRoseman  I think so too. But for sheer correctness should the code throw any error?

Comment: I would really prefer to inherit, if at all possible. The third party object is a RecurringEvent object with complex behavior, and I'd like my model to have that same behavior, without proxying or serializing or bridging or other efforts. It's really an "is-a" relationship, rather than "has-a".

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, I have been chasing in the wrong direction: The multiple inheritance code above actually works. The error was that I added the following field to ModelForThirdPartyClass:

```
foo = models.DecimalField(19, 4)
```

whereas I should have written

```
foo = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=4)
```

Since the field definition is evaluated at the time where the class is created, I misinterpreted the error as to being related to resolving the inheritance.